# get a guid of an list item of a sharepoint list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, guid

Im using SPDataSource to bind a sharepoint list to a repeater control

within the itemtemplate of the repeater i am using things such as

<%# Eval("Title") %>

im trying to get an id for the list item, ideally something like a guid eg

but the above does not work... how can i get a guid?
btw i did <%# Eval("ID") %> this worked however it returns a number e.g 1, 2, 3..

ideally i want something more like a guid.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ugly, but works

```
<%# ((SPListItem)((SPDataSourceViewResultItem)Container.DataItem).ResultItem).UniqueId %>
```

Don't forget to add

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>   
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Simple way

```
<%# Eval("UniqueId") %>
```

works only if you set *IncludeHidden* to true on your SPDataSource

Answer (score 1):

The SPListItem property UniqueId is the unique identifier for the item.

So try

```
<%# Eval("UniqueId") %>
```

Please note the case sensitivity.

Comment: The OP is looking for the unique ID of a list item, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<%# Eval("UniqueId") %>`

Comment: I tried that and heres what i get:
System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceViewResultItem' does not contain a property with the name 'UniqueID'.

Comment: @raklos: Try UniqueId (Note the lower case 'd'). See the casing of the link in my answer.

Comment: still doesnt work :( .... System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceViewResultItem' does not contain a property with the name 'UniqueId'.

Answer (score 0):

The GUID for a list item is stored in [SPListItem.UniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.uniqueid.aspx).

Comment: but how do i get that using eval?